# I want to show images in my "index" with some delay

Tags: node.js

The images are named as "0.png", "1.png"...

at the moment I can only see the fourth picture.
How can I make them all show with 0.5 seconds delay?

```
const rootComponent = {
    template: `<div style="text-align:center">
   <QR/>
  </div>`,
};

const QRComponent = {
    created: function() {
      for(let x=1;x<5;x++)
       {
          this.img = "685287/"+x+".png";
      }
    },
    template: `<div class="QR"> <img v-bind:src='img'></div>`
};
const app = Vue.createApp(rootComponent);
app.component('QR', QRComponent);
const vm = app.mount("#app");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your for loop is renaming the same property 4 times before returning. By the time the template is evaluated, this.img is only assigned to the most recent value in the loop. You need to do one of two things:

- get rid of the loop and create 4 QR components that each set this.img only once
- change this.img to an array and make your template iterate over the image array.

I'm not familiar with vue, but to get the 500ms delay you could probably set the values of this.img in a window.setTimeout()